# How to use installed package on node.js?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, wordpress

I'm using [FoundationPress](https://github.com/olefredrik/foundationpress/) theme for WordPress and installed it using Node.js. Now I want to install [Perfect Scrollbar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) and I did so using `npm install perfect-scrollbar` but I don't know how to use it. I can now see it under node_modules. I don't know where to import the css and the js file.

I import .scss using the foundation.scss file. I'm adding the js by adding a .js file to js/custom and then running `grunt build`.

Do I also put it there or there's a nicer way to use the installed package? I've also run `grunt build` but didn't see the script running in my theme.

I'm using Git Bash command line to do all this. Not sure if that helps. I have only started using Node.js

Comment: try to install using npm install --save and then try  npm run build